# ArcGIS Pro Auto save file format (.save)

Tags: arcgis-pro

My ArcGIS Pro 1.4 has crashed and I noticed it saves an Auto-save file (.save) but I can't open it. The only file formats I can open are .aprx and .ppkx. Arc Pro doesn't suggest any auto-save version (like Microsoft Word for example) as I reopen the project neither.

Any methods to restore the auto-save?

Comment: Have you tried renaming .save to .aprx and trying to open that?  Make sure you work on copies because that is just a guess rather than something that I have tried or read.

Comment: I am not aware of ArcGIS Pro supporting automatic saving (of projects).  It does support [automatic saving of feature edits](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/editing/change-settings-for-saving-edits.htm) but that is a completely different thing.

Comment: @PolyGeo I changed the .save file's format to .aprx but it failed to open. The error is ''This project was saved using a newer version of ArcGIS Pro''.

Comment: @Midavalo exactly! surprisingly I can't find any resources about project auto-save

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not an option for ArcGIS Pro. It is an idea that is under consideration though: https://community.esri.com/ideas/1079-add-an-autosave-feature-for-arcgis-desktop.

Answer (score 0):

This is now an option (activated by default with a 5 min interval) at last since version 3.0.

From the ESRI help page :

> - Open the Settings page : From the ArcGIS Pro start page, click the Settings tab Settings. From an open project, click the Project tab on the ribbon.
> - In the list on the left, click Options.
> - On the Options dialog box, under Application, click General.
> - Under Project Recovery, indicate whether project backups should be    created while you work.
>
>   - Check Create a backup when the project has unsaved changes to always    create backups while you work on a project.
>   - Uncheck Create a backup when the project has unsaved changes to never    create backups.
> - Optionally, change the time interval.
> - Click OK.

See here for full detail : [Help>Projects>Work with projects](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.0/help/projects/save-a-project.htm)